# Splitting a line in bash based on delimiter with Sed / Regex

Tags: regex, bash, sed

Regex rookie and hoping to change that. I have the following seemingly very simple problem that I cannot figure the correct regex implementation to parse properly. Basically I have a file that has lines that looks like this:

```
time:3:35PM
```

I am just trying to cut out all characters up to and including ONLY FIRST ':' delimiter and keep the rest intact with sed so that I can process on many files with same format. What I am trying to get is this:

```
3:35PM
```

The below is the closest I got but is just using the last occurrence of the delimiter instead of the first.:

```
sed 's/.*://'
```

I have also tried with python but have challenges with applying a python function to iterate through all lines in many files as opposed to just one file.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Greedy match, eh? `:)` Give a shot to this one: `sed 's/[^:]*://'`

Answer (score 4):

You can do this in just about every text processing tool (many without using regular expressions at all).

### ed

If the in-place editing is really important, the canonical correct way is not sed (the *stream* editor) but `ed` (the *file* editor).

```
ed "$file" << EOF
,s/^[^:]*://g
w
EOF
```

### sed

(Pretty much the same commands as ed, formatted a little differently)

```
sed 's/^[^:]*://' < "$file" > "$file".new
mv "$file".new "$file"
```

### BASH

This one doesn't cause any new processes to be spawned. (For whatever that's worth.)

```
while IFS=: read _ time; do
    printf '%s\n' "$time"
done < "$file" > "$file".new
mv "$file".new "$file"
```

### awk

```
awk -F: 'BEGIN{ OFS=":" } { print $2,$3 }' < "$file" > "$file".new
mv "$file".new "$file"
```

### cut

```
cut -d: -f2- < "$file" > "$file".new
mv "$file".new "$file"
```

Comment: Nice! Did not even know about 'ed'. Thank you. Can I ask how you might apply the ed option recursively with multiple directories containing multiple files?

Comment: @prometheus2305 If your shell can recursively glob, you can just loop over that glob expression, like `for f in **/*; do ed "$f" <<< "$edscript"; done`. Otherwise you'd need to use `find` with a script. Something like `find . -type f -name "$filepattern" -exec sh -c 'ed "$1" <<< "$edscript"' _ {} \;`

Comment: This is pretty comprehensive. I would do `mv "${file}" "${file}.bak"`"  first and then use `< "${file}.bak" > "${file}"` for the edit, leaving a backup file in case of accidents.

Answer (score 3):

Since you don't need a regular expression to match a single, known character, consider using [cut](/questions/tagged/cut) instead of [sed](/questions/tagged/sed).

This simple expression sets `:` as the `d`-elimiter and emits `f`-ields `2`, onwards (`-`):

```
cut -d: -f2-
```

Example:

```
% echo 'time:3:35PM' | cut -d: -f2-
3:35PM
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried this but it's my understanding that you can't use cut for in place editing for multiple files.

Comment: @prometheus2305: True enough, [tag:cut] doesn't do in-place editing but neither doe all [tag:sed] implementations.

Comment: thank you. I'm definitely focused on in-place editing. So if I'm understanding correctly, I need to go with 'ed'

Comment: @prometheus2305: [tag:ed] would certainly do the job (as illustrated in [kojiro's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18806742/78845)). Use whichever tool you're most comfortable using.

Answer (score 2):

[kojiro's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18806742/2698019) has a plenty of great alternatives, but you have asked how to do that with `regex`. Here are some pure regex solutions:

```
grep -oP '[^:]*:\K.*' file.txt
```

`\K` makes it forget everything before the occurrence of `\K`.
But if you know the exact prefix length then you can use [lookaround](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) feature:

```
grep -oP '(?<=^time:).*' file.txt
```

Note that most of regex implementations do not support these features. You can use it in `grep` with `-P` flag and `perl` itself. I wonder if any other utility supports these.

Answer (score 1):

To remove every instance up to `:` and including the `:` you could do..

```
sed -i.bak 's/^[^:]*://' file.txt
```

on multiple `.txt` files

```
sed -i.bak 's/^[^:]*://' *.txt
```

The `-i` option specifies that files are to be edited in-place. By creating a temporary file and sending output to this file rather than to the standard output.

Answer (score 0):

Please consider my answer here:

[How to use regex with cut at the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43312360/how-to-use-regex-with-cut-at-the-command-line/59833673#59833673)

You could for example just write:

```sh
echo 'time:3:35PM' | cutr -d : -f 2- -r :
```

In your particular case, you could simply use `cut` though:

```sh
echo 'time:3:35PM' | cut -d : -f 2-
```

Any feedback welcome. `cutr` isn't perfect yet, but before I invest too much time into it, I wanted to get some feedback.