# How to use regex with cut at the command line?

Tags: sed, centos, cut

I have some output like this from `ls -alth`:

```
drwxr-xr-x    5 root    admin   170B Aug  3  2016 ..
drwxr-xr-x    5 root    admin    70B Aug  3  2016 ..
drwxr-xr-x    5 root    admin     3B Aug  3  2016 ..
drwxr-xr-x    5 root    admin     9M Aug  3  2016 ..
```

Now, I want to parse out the `170B` part, which is obviously the size in human readable format.  I wanted to do this using `cut` or `sed`, because I don't want to use tools that are any more complicated/difficult to use than necessary.

Ideally I want it to be robust enough to handle the `B`, `M` or `K` suffix that comes with the size, and multiply accordingly by `1`, `1000000` and `1000` accordingly.  I haven't found a good way to do that, though.

I've tried a few things without really knowing the best approach:

```
ls -alth | cut -f 5 -d \s+
```

I was hoping that would work because I'd be able to just delimit it on *one or more spaces*.

But that doesn't work.  How do I supply `cut` with a regex delimiter?  or is there an easier way to extract only the size of the file from `ls -alth`?

I'm using CentOS6.4

Comment: Why not just `ls -alth |cut -d" " -f5` ..?

Comment: I have actually never heard of that option. That doesn't work because it needs to split on any number of spaces.  your example only splits on one space.  I added a few more example lines to the question to make it a bit more clear.

Comment: OK then... What about `ls -alth |awk '{print $5}' ` ? This works by default with any white space . By the way, even with cut works in my Debian.

Comment: I was trying to avoid `awk`, because it is an unfamiliar tool for me.  That might work though.  Please write a complete answer for me to see your organized thinking process as well as tradeoffs.

Answer (score 8):

<sup>This answer tackles the question *as asked*, but consider [George Vasiliou's helpful `find` solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43312948/45375) as a potentially superior alternative.</sup>

- `cut` only supports a *single*, literal character as the delimiter (`-d`), so it isn't the right tool to use.
- For extracting tokens (fields) that are separated with a variable amount of whitespace per line, `awk` is the best tool, so the solution proposed by [George Vasiliou](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3988526/george-vasiliou) is the simplest one:
  `ls -alth | awk '{print $5}'`
  extracts the 5th whitespace-separated field (`$5`), which is the size.
- Rather than use `-h` first and then reconvert the human-readable suffixes (such as `B`, `M`, and `G`) back to the mere *byte* counts (incidentally, the multipliers must be multiples of `1024`, not `1000`), simply omit `-h` from the `ls` command, which outputs the raw byte counts by default:
  `ls -alt | awk '{print $5}'`

Comment: That's actually a great ida to omit the `-h` flag from `ls -alth`.  I hadn't thought of that.

Answer (score 2):

Alternative to the awk solution that will treat whitespace correctly , one can also use the `find` utility that can provide results similar to `ls`.

Actually you can use `find` to display directly size of the results without the need of any other tool/pipe like `cut` or `awk`.

So, to list mere bytes you can use:

```
$ find . -maxdepth 1 -printf %s\\n
173
3
684
```

You can combine filename + bytes in find with

```
$ find . -maxdepth 1 -printf %f-%s\\n
bsd.txt-173
file4-3
shellcolors.sh-684
```

You can consult `man find` to see a lot of available options under `-printf`.

Moreover, by removing `-maxdepth` option you can also have a listing of all the files in the subdirectories.

One more alternative is to use `du` utility, that is capable to provide results in human readable format:

```
$ du -a -b -h -d1
1.9M    ./appsfiles
173 ./bsd.txt
3   ./file4
684 ./shellcolors.sh
```

`-a` : all files and directories. Remove this option to get only directories size
`-b` : Reports the real size of file - Removing this option will report the disk size occupied by this file (i.e a file of 3 kB occupies 4K in reality)
`-h` : human readable size
`-d1` : depth1

You can further parse the results of du with `|cut -d" " -f1` or with `|awk '{print $1}'`

Answer (score 1):

I was getting annoyed with having to look up awk(ward) syntax and wrote my own:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cutr

Install with

```sh
npm i -g cutr
ls --full-time | cutr -d ' +' -f 6-
```

or run with something like

```sh
ls --full-time | npx cutr -d ' +' -f 6-
```

Your command could be

```sh
ls -alth | cutr -f 5 -d '\s+'
```